# Can't import .so file due to permissions missing: failed to map segment from shared object

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-import, .so

I'm trying to run a custom project that uses large parts of the [SiamMask](https://github.com/foolwood/SiamMask) project. When the code is ran, one of the many imports is this one:

```
from . import region
```

located in an `__init__.py` file. It is trying to import a .so file called `region.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` which is located in the same directory as the `__init__.py` file.

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /scratch/[hidden]/project/libs/siamMask/utils/pyvotkit/region.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
```

I'm pretty confident that this error is caused due to the following fact. The scratch disk I'm working on, which is mounted to the GPU server, doesn't have direct 'execute' permissions for Python related things. (There's nothing I can change about this) This is also the reason why the Python virtual environment I'm working on is located on a different drive (where the system has direct execute permissions on everything that is Python related).

My question however is, how can I import this .so file in a different way that wouldn't interfere with the above fact? Could I transfer the file to the other drive and somehow import it from there via that `__init__` file?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue in the following way:

I moved the `region.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file to the other drive where Python can execute. I then used the following code in the `__init__` file:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/.sofile')

import region
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a virtual environment on a separate disk, and the reason for denied access was `user` flag set for the disk with git repository in `/etc/fstab`.

After removing the flag and remounting the disk, the error was gone