# Cloud Jupyter notebook Numpy .so file "failed to map segment from shared object"

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm using the webbased Jupyter Notebook.

I've been getting this import error, so I checked the provided link, decided to reinstall Numpy.

```
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

  * The Python version is: Python3.7 from "/usr/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.20.3"

Original error was: /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

So I used `pip uninstall numpy` and then proceeded with `y` when asked.

How long does this usually take? It's been running for at least two hours by now. Is it supposed to take this long?

Is there an alternative solution for this?

I've tried `sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev` but this just returns a Syntax error.

Comment: No, it should be practically instantaneous... A few seconds maybe

Comment: What do you mean a "webbased notebook"?

Comment: It seems this issue you're having relates to executable flags on the cloud drive, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64419585/8763097) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724726/cant-import-so-file-due-to-permissions-missing-failed-to-map-segment-from-sha) and [here](https://discuss.tvm.apache.org/t/solved-failed-to-map-segment-from-shared-object/3035). Tricky problem, not sure what to suggest beyond reading through these.